# Double clicking to do the 'edge ring' or 'edge loop' selection in Blender 2.8

Tags: selection-tools

In 2.79, I can double click any vertex/edge/face to do edge-ring selection or edge-loop selection. I just need to click the proper spot to switch between these two modes. But seems this feature is gone in 2.8 ? Does anyone know what happen? This is handy because i can simply double click it while in 2.8 i can have the same functions but need to press alt or ctrl etc. Does anyone know how to get this double click feature back in 2.8 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Enable "Emulate 3 Button Mouse" in Preferences > Input to get double-click loop selection back. There's a [discussion](https://developer.blender.org/T58963) on the dev forum about it. Basically, double-click broke two features – Selection Cycling and Select All Boundaries – according to the developers, which is why they disabled it without having 3 Button Mouse emulation enabled.